# Drupal: How to use fieldsets in hook_field_widget_form

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-7, fieldset

So I have my hook_field_schema defining columns, and hook_field_widget_form is set up and saving all of the column values correctly.

But as soon as I put two of the fields inside of a fieldset, those values never save or get updated. I've tried setting #tree => FALSE all over the place and that isn't working either.

What am I missing? Is it just unsupported? Should I be using a form_alter hook or something to move them into a fieldset?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution. After trying many things, it turned out to be something as simple as illogical. Well, in the eyes of a Drupal newbie.

At first I had something like this (stripped down version):

```
$element['mymodulefieldset'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Fieldset title',
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
);
```

and added fields to the fieldset:

```
$element['mymodulefieldset']['fieldname'] = array(
  '#title' => "Field title",
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => '',
);
```

After trying lots of different scenarios I found out the next lines of code did (sort of) work. Instead of inserting a fieldset, I turned the element into a fieldset like this:

```
$element += array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#tree' => true
);
```

Then I added fields to the element:

```
$element['fieldname'] = array(
  '#title' => "Field title",
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => '',
);
```

NB: some variables like #title and #weight are controlled by "Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » [YOUR CONTENT TYPE]", others (like #collapsible and #collapsed) can be defined here.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: I'm voting this answer up because it will definitely be helpful to others searching for fieldset information, but this wasn't my issue. I had some form fields inside of a fieldset, and some outside of one, and the ones inside weren't saving.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old question, but there is a solution for this problem, explained [in this artice](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/poutine-maker-introduction-field-api-drupal-7-part-1), the `#process` part is what is used to save the fields properly.

**EDIT:** As the comment of @alexkb explains, the author of the article has updated his [custom field sample](https://github.com/tarmstrong/poutine_maker) and has removed the #process hack. For a better solution, use the GitHub code.

Comment: The article you've linked to talks about #process but you'll notice the author has updated his [sample code on github](https://github.com/tarmstrong/poutine_maker/blob/master/poutine_maker.module) to use hook_field_presave() - which is a much better approach than the #process hack. I'm voting your answer up though, as it led me to a solution that I thought I wouldn't be able to solve, thanks!

Comment: i found by myself the solution using hook_field_presave but be aware that with that solution the code ` '#default_value' => isset($item['value']) ? $item['value'] : ''` won't work in case of fields attached to entities like paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [physical module](https://www.drupal.org/project/physical). Basically do:

```
$element['#type'] = 'fieldset'
```

You can define the sub fields with:

```
$element['subfield'] = array (...);
```